# Iterating in a For Loop to check if previous value is greater than current value

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, indexing, np

```
pitch_per_ab = []
pitch_of_pa = pitcher['PitchofPA']

for i in range(len(pitch_of_pa)):
    prev_elem = pitch_of_pa[i-1]
    current_elem = pitch_of_pa[i]
    if current_elem <= prev_elem:
       np.append(pitch_per_ab, prev_elem)
    
pitch_per_ab
```

This is my current code, when I run it i get a KeyError that simply says "-1":
[photo of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMlal.png)

Ideally, it would run and if the previous value in pitch_of_pa is greater than the current, than it will append the previous value to the list pitch_per_ab

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This is happens due to:

```
prev_elem = pitch_of_pa[i-1]
```

`i` starts in `0` and when this row is executed, the value `-1` causes the error:

```
KeyError: -1
```